# Specify Dynamically Created EBS Volume Names

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, amazon-eks

When dynamically creating Persistent Volumes in a K8s cluster running on EKS, using gp2 as the default storage class, is it possible to name the EBS volumes that are created?

Currently, they get names like `kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-d8896767-a1c9-11e9-bb21-0e3fcd7b2ecc` but it would be nice for volume management to have the labels be more clear.

Comment: How are you creating PVs dynamically? Are you just defining PVC and let K8s create PVs?

Comment: Yes, exactly - most are currently dynamically provisioned by K8s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic provisioning is managed by [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#defaultstorageclass), so there's **no** straight way to control naming of the volumes.